# mysql indexes / ordering data based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a simple table "t1" that contains:

```
word VARCHAR(16)
id INT
importance SMALLINT
```

word and id are unique together, but neither is unique alone.

I added a `UNIQUE INDEX(word, id)`

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE word = "something" ORDER BY importance DESC
```

But it takes 0.0002 seconds to execute say:

```
SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE word = "something"
```

But takes as much as 0.15s to execute the `ORDER BY importance DESC`.

My question is, how can I index/reorder my table so it's organized firstly by word, then by importance without having to do the sorting on the fly?

Can I just reorder the static data so it's sorted by `word, importance DESC` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up your query, add an index on `(word, importance DESC, id)`.

You can have more than one index on a table so you don't need to remove your existing index if you don't want to.

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem comes in when I populate the table. I want to make sure I don't add multiple word, id pairs. What do you think?

Comment: @nick: As I said, you don't need to remove your unique index. You can have both indexes at the same time.

Comment: Won't that double the disk space?

Comment: I suppose I can allow some duplicates and filter those out later. Thanks.